# Google Maps distance matrix zip "zero results"

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When requesting a distance using a zip code some cities consistently return "ZERO RESULTS", although when making the same request using the city name it returns the expected distance. 
For example:

[Palo Alto to Twentynine Palms using zip](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=92277&destinations=94301&mode=driving&language=en&sensor=false)

[Palo Alto to Twentynine Palms using name](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=twentyninepalms,ca&destinations=94301&mode=driving&language=en&sensor=false)

Google maps recognizes both zip codes, but still returns "ZERO Results".
Is it a bug or am I missing something in my request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like the geocoded value of 92277 (the zip code for Twentynine Palms) is too far from the road to yield driving directions:

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=92277&addr2=94301&geocode=1

Comment: That's so weird that the name of the town and the zip don't have the same geolocation. Thanks.

Comment: I suspect the zip code geolocation is the centroid of the ZCTA, not the location of the town.

Comment: That [zipcode has a strange shape](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTablesLayer_linktoA.html?lat=34.205834&lng=-115.754424&zoom=10&type=m&tableid=1499916&tablequery=SELECT%20geometry%20FROM%201499916%20WHERE%20ZIP%20%3D92277)

Comment: hmmm interesting. Until you pointed it out I hadn't realized that Distance Matrix only returns travel distance, while I needed the real (as the crow flies) distance - had to use computeDistanceBetween (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween) - the Haversine Formula.